# Reducing MDIconButton Background Size Using Python and Kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy, kivymd

I have this simple code that creates a MDIconButton:

```
icon = MDIconButton(
    icon = "close-circle",
    md_bg_color = "red",
    theme_icon_color = "Custom",
    icon_color = "white",
    pos_hint = {"top": 1, "right": 1},
    icon_size = "18sp",
)
```

However, it's too big for the widget I want to put it in. I've tried reducing its size using the `icon_sise` attribute but at some point the background becomes bigger than the size of the icon itself.

Is it possible to reduce, or ideally entirely eliminate the background/padding of the MDIconWidget?

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the background by setting the `_md_bg_color` property of the `MDIconButton` to transparent. But setting it in the construction of the button does not seem to work. Try something like this:

```
def set_bg_color(self, button, _dt):
    # set the _md_bg_color to transparent
    button._md_bg_color = [1, 1, 1, 0]
```

And call that method after the button is created:

```
    icon = MDIconButton(
        icon="close-circle",
        md_bg_color="red",
        theme_icon_color="Custom",
        # icon_color="white",   # if icon is white, it may blend in with background
        icon_color="red",
        pos_hint={"top": 1, "right": 1},
        icon_size="6sp",
    )
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.set_bg_color, icon))
```